# Continuity of Function W.R.T. Topology Generated by a Function

Tags: general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be some metric space, and let $x_0 \in X$ be some fixed point.  Denote by $\mathcal{T}_0$ the topology with respect to which $x \mapsto d(x_0,x)$ is continuous. My question is,

> If $x_1 \neq x_0$, will the map $x \mapsto d(x_1,x)$ be continuous wrt $(X,\mathcal{T}_0)$?

I've tried to prove that it is true but had no luck, so I suspect that it is false. However, I'm having trouble coming up with a counterexample. In term of trying to find a counterexample, I considered the function $f_0 : \Bbb{R} \to [0,\infty)$ and the topology $\mathcal{T}_0$ wrt it is continuous, and then tried showing that $f_1 : \Bbb{R} \to [0,\infty)$ via $f(x) = |1-x|$ is not continuous wrt $(\Bbb{R},\mathcal{T}_0)$ by considering various pullbacks of closed sets. Sadly, I didn't have much luck. I could use some help sorting all of this out.

Going back to the setup at the beginning of this post, ultimately I am trying to prove that $\mathcal{T}_0$ is finer than the metric topology. If I *could* show that $x \mapsto d(x_1,x)$ is in fact continuous wrt $(X,\mathcal{T}_0)$, then I would have an easy proof that $\mathcal{T}_0$ is finer than the metric topology.

Comment: I think either the old prelim has an error or you have copied it wrong.  First of all, there is no such thing as "_the_ topology with respect to which $x\mapsto d(x_0,x)$".  Second of all, assuming $\mathcal{T}_0$ is just supposed to be an arbitrary topology with this property, you need the property to hold for _every_ $x_0\in X$, not just for some fixed $x_0$.  It is not true if you just have one $x_0$.

Comment: @EricWofsey You're right. The problem uses the indefinite article, but I am not sure I follow your second point. Here's the prelim: https://www.albany.edu/math/images/prelims/top1601.pdf

Comment: Yeah, the problem definitely intends to have a universal quantifier on $x_0$, not an existential quantifier.  The phrasing with "fix a point $x_0\in X$" at the start is a mistake.  (It is correct for the first half of the problem but not the second half.)

Comment: @EricWofsey Ah, so $\mathcal{T}_0$ is a topology on $X$ with respect to which $y \mapsto d(x,y)$ is continuous for every $x \in X$?

Comment: Right, that's the intended meaning of the second part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an answer if you read the question verbatim: consider $\mathbb R$ with the usual metric. One topology which makes $x \to d(x,0)$ continuous is the collection of sets of the form $\{x:|x| \in U\}$ where $U$ is open in $\mathbb R$. The function $x \to d(x,1)$ is not continuous in this topology  because $\{x: |x-1| <1\}=(0,2)$ is not of the form $\{x:|x| \in U\}$ for any open set $U$. [ Sets of the the latter type are all symmetric about $0$].